# Hibernate audit history reader exception

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I configured auditing through hibernate-envers library and it works fine, until I wanted to read the history through AuditReader API.

This is the code:

```
AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
List<Number> revisionNumbers = auditReader.getRevisions(Queue.class, queue.getId());
        for (Number rev : revisionNumbers) {
            Queue auditedQueue = auditReader.find(Queue.class, queue.getId(), rev);
            audQueues.add(auditedQueue);
        }
```

The exception thrown is **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: smallint <> bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 879**

I configured sql logging and I see the failing query:

```
select queue_aud0_.ID as ID12_, queue_aud0_.REV as REV12_, queue_aud0_.REVTYPE as REVTYPE12_ from CMSMS_QUEUE_AUD queue_aud0_ where (queue_aud0_.REV=(select max(queue_aud1_.REV) from CMSMS_QUEUE_AUD queue_aud1_ where (queue_aud1_.REV<=? )and(queue_aud0_.ID=queue_aud1_.ID )))and(queue_aud0_.REVTYPE<>? )and(queue_aud0_.ID=? )
```

There are more columns selected but they are not important right now... The parameters used by hibernate are:

```
bindNamedParameters() TEST_NEW -> _p1 [3]
bindNamedParameters() DEL -> _p0 [2]
bindNamedParameters() 5 -> revision [1]
```

I tried running the query with these parameters and it throws the same exception. The reason is the second parameter **queue_aud0_.REVTYPE<>?**, because hibernate is trying to set there 'DEL' string while REVTYPE is smallint. Thats weird, because the tables were auto generated by hibernate... Any idea why does it do this??

I use version 4.2.0.Final

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It isn't being bound to a string but instead to an Enum.  What Hibernate places in the log is the Enum's value, in this case the `#getRevisions` query you are running filters out REVTYPE=(2/DEL) entries.  As to why the query fails, perhaps there's an issue with enum handling in that version.  I assume you're using hibernate-core 4.2.0.Final as well?

Comment: Yes, I see hibernate-core 4.2.0.Final in Maven Dependencies (though i didnt set it in pom.xml, so I guess it is child of some other dependency). Anyway, it is really weird, because the audit writing works fine, it sets the enum value as number, but this select operation sets it as string...

Comment: Are you in a position where you can try with a more recent version?  Version 4.2 is no longer being developed or maintained.

Comment: Thanks. I played a little with dependencies and now it works. I switched Hibernate to 5.3.0.Final, SpringFramework to 5.0.5.RELEASE and removed some JPA dependency that was probably redundant. It seems to work now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a bit with dependencies, it works now. I switched Hibernate to 5.3.0.Final and SpringFramework to 5.0.5.RELEASE. Also had remove some JPA dependency that was redundant. Cannot say exactly, what solved the problem, since I had to change these all dependencies together to even run the application.